# How to deal with model evaluation within lapply?

Tags: r, environment-variables, lapply

I am having an issue using the `pscore.test` function from the `segmented` package (I believe) because it internally calls for an evaluation of my model frame in an environment outside that which the model was initially made. Below is the code and error backtrace:

```
ESs <- c("comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233")

models <- lapply(ESs, function(i){
  lm(EL ~ temp, data=subset(data, es_code == i))
})


library(segmented)

lapply(models, function(i) pscore.test(i, seg.Z=~temp))
```

Resulting error message:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = es_code == i`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'i' not found
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─BiocGenerics::lapply(models, function(i) pscore.test(i, seg.Z = ~temp))
  2. ├─base::lapply(models, function(i) pscore.test(i, seg.Z = ~temp))
  3. │ └─global FUN(X[[i]], ...)
  4. │   └─segmented::pscore.test(i, seg.Z = ~temp)
  5. │     ├─base::eval(mf)
  6. │     │ └─base::eval(mf)
  7. │     ├─stats::model.frame(...)
  8. │     ├─stats::model.frame.default(...)
  9. │     │ └─base::is.data.frame(data)
 10. │     ├─dplyr::filter(data, es_code == i)
 11. │     └─dplyr:::filter.data.frame(data, es_code == i)
 12. │       └─dplyr:::filter_rows(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
 13. │         └─dplyr:::filter_eval(dots, mask = mask, error_call = error_call)
 14. │           ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 15. │           └─mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
 16. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 17.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
 18.     └─rlang::abort(bullets, call = error_call, parent = skip_internal_condition(e))
```

I get the same issue even if I create the `lm` and input it into `pscore.test` in the apply statement. I'm not sure how to deal with this issue.

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(EL = c(0.105914718019257, 0.00572519083969466, 
                                                     0.875763747454175, 0.709941520467836, 0.0230607966457023, 0.00131061598951507, 
                                                     0.88255033557047, 0.627272727272727, 0.127433628318584, 0.0772676371780515, 
                                                     0.794117647058823, 0.619552414605418, 0.610021786492375, 0.284644194756554, 
                                                     0.0939490445859873, 0.0137420718816068, 0.0749128919860627, 0.01, 
                                                     0.868312757201646, 0.643356643356643, 0.543909348441926, 0.258706467661692, 
                                                     0.822709163346614, 0.568459657701711, 0.27190332326284, 0.104795737122558, 
                                                     0.579497907949791, 0.464713715046605, 0.563583815028902, 0.374376039933444, 
                                                     0.460405156537753, 0.160046728971963, 0.531353135313531, 0.349532710280374, 
                                                     0.319230769230769, 0.141025641025641, 0.589473684210526, 0.42258064516129, 
                                                     0.602040816326531, 0.254752851711027, 0.965699208443272, 0.788273615635179, 
                                                     0.96280276816609, 0.842271293375394, 0.987025023169602, 0.894894894894895, 
                                                     0.966329966329966, 0.748914616497829, 0.946175637393768, 0.989655172413793, 
                                                     0.825665859564165, 0.942332896461337, 0.928571428571429, 0.957163958641064, 
                                                     0.934981684981685, 0.96353591160221, 0.955985915492958, 0.948051948051948, 
                                                     0.9140625, 0.920071047957371, 0.959531416400426, 0.947741364038973, 
                                                     0.965025906735751), temp = c(23L, 23L, 10L, 10L, 25L, 25L, 10L, 
                                                                                                             10L, 25L, 25L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 14L, 14L, 
                                                                                                             18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 
                                                                                                             20L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 12L, 23L, 10L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 
                                                                                                             10L, 25L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 
                                                                                                             16L, 20L, 16L, 20L), es_code = c("comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -63L))
```

Here's my session info:

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] segmented_1.6-4 nlme_3.1-157    MASS_7.3-57    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1  tools_4.2.1     rstudioapi_0.13 splines_4.2.1   grid_4.2.1      lattice_0.20-45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subset=` argument of `lm` can help you with this.

```
ESs <- c("comp137978_c1_seq3:415", "comp137978_c1_seq3:475", "comp138286_c0_seq1:1233")

models <- lapply(ESs, function(i) {
  lm(EL ~ temp, data=data, subset=es_code == i)
})

lapply(models, function(i) segmented::pscore.test(i, seg.Z=~temp))
# [[1]]
# 
#   Score test for one/two changes in the slope
# 
# data:  formula = EL ~ temp 
# breakpoint for variable = temp 
# model = gaussian , link = identity , method = lm
# observed value = -1.2351, n.points = 10, p-value = 0.2327
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided   (1 breakpoint) 
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#   Score test for one/two changes in the slope
# 
# data:  formula = EL ~ temp 
# breakpoint for variable = temp 
# model = gaussian , link = identity , method = lm
# observed value = 0.26025, n.points = 10, p-value = 0.7976
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided   (1 breakpoint) 
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
#   Score test for one/two changes in the slope
# 
# data:  formula = EL ~ temp 
# breakpoint for variable = temp 
# model = gaussian , link = identity , method = lm
# observed value = -2.2314, n.points = 10, p-value = 0.03669
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided   (1 breakpoint)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error: `Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'i' not found`...

Comment: I added my session info in case is why it's not working for my end.